# Take a screenshot of an entire webpage using Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, webpage-screenshot

I have a problem on taking a screenshot using robotframework.

Currently I am using keyword Capture Page Screenshot on Selenium2library. The problem is that, keyword only captures the webpage visible on the screen.
We needed a screenshot that could take the entire webpage. This means that when it capture a screenshot it should scroll down to the bottom of the webpage and capture the whole page. Is that possible?

Appreciate everyone can suggest if there are other library that we  can use.

Comment: Are you using chrome? Do you have the option of using firefox? At least on linux, the firefox screenshots take the whole page.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a headless browser:

http://phantomjs.org/

Execute it from Python as a separate process if you need to, storing the result into a file.

Comment: We are using jython by the way and chrome as a browser.